# A system of particles distributed on the surface of a ball, what is the "center of mass" of them on the surface?

Tags: geometry, centroid

Suppose a system of $n$ particles distributed on the surface of a ball, what is the "center of mass" of them on the surface?
Does the following optimization problem have an analytical solution?

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol {P}     =\operatorname*{argmin}_{c\in  {\Omega} } \;\sum _{i=1}^{n}m_{i}  d^2 {\left(c, p_i \right)}  
\end{equation}

Where $\Omega$ is the surface of the ball, $m_i$ is particle $p_i$'s mass.

$d^2 \left(c, p_i \right)$ is the squared distanced from  $c$ to particle $p_i$ on the surface. That is to say, it is the squared great-circle distance.

Suppose we know each particle's coordinate $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$.

Comment: Typical applications of the concept of centre of mass make less sense in a non-euclidean context, though.

Comment: The point of minimum or maximum may not be unique. That definitely happens when there is a fairly large symmetry group of the points, like the group of a cube. On the other hand, there exist some notions of the average of a distribution over a circle ( or sphere?) but I don't know details.

Comment: If you're only interested in this particular formula I can't help you, but my advice is not to use the distance on the surface of the sphere as though we're in a euclidean space; I'd suggest, instead of the distance squared, to use some other measure, like the dot product of the positions of the particles (one of the advantages of this is that you get a function which is differentiable everywhere, while yours has non-differentiable points opposite every particle).

Comment: It is the "center of mass" on a manifold, the surface of a ball is a manifold. Right? It is like the system of particles are distributing on a plane.

Comment: @Mike Mathcook With your proposal, the result wouldn't  be intrinsical : it would depend upon the parametrization of the surface.

Comment: In the case of 4 points which are vertices of a regular tetrahedron, what would be the candidate for being the "mid-point" on the surface of the sphere ? This example shows that you will be facing big difficulties in trying to give a correct meaning for this "center of mass"...

Comment: "A hypersphere is the four-dimensional analog of a sphere. Although a sphere exists in 3-space, its surface is two-dimensional. Similarly, a hypersphere has a three-dimensional surface which curves into 4-space. Our universe could be the hyper-surface of a hypersphere." What we see a straight line in the 3-space is just a curve in 4-space.
The "center of mass" we got in 3-space could just be the "center of mass" on a manifold in 4-space.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_mean

Answer (score 3):

The great circle distance between two points $\ c\ $ and $\ p_i\ $ on the surface of a ball is proportional to the angle subtended by the points at centre of the ball—that is, to
$$
\arccos\left(\frac{\langle c,p_i\rangle}{\|c\|\,\|p_i\|}\right)\ .
$$
To simplify matters, choose your unit of distance to be the radius of the ball, so that $\ \|p_i\|=1\ $ for all $\ i\ $, and the condition $\ c\in\Omega\ $ is equivalent to $\ \|c\|^2=1\ $.  Your optimisation problem then reduces to
\begin{align}
&\min_{c\in\mathbb{R}^3}\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\arccos\big(\langle c,p_i\rangle\big)^2\\
&\text{subject to: }\ \|c\|^2=1\ .
\end{align}
The [Lagrange condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Single_constraint_2) for the minimum is
$$
{\Large\sum_{i=1}^n}\frac{m_i\arccos\big(\langle c,p_i\rangle\big) p_i}{\sqrt{1-\langle c,p_i\rangle^2}}-\lambda c=0\ .
$$
From this and the condition $\ \|c\|^2=1\ $, we get
$$
\lambda^2={\Large\sum_{i=1}^n}{\Large\sum_{j=1}^n}\frac{m_im_j\arccos\big(\langle c,p_i\rangle\big)\arccos\big(\langle c,p_j\rangle\big)\langle p_i,p_j\rangle}{\sqrt{1-\langle c,p_i\rangle^2}\sqrt{1-\langle c,p_j\rangle^2}}\ .
$$
Since we're looking for the minimum of the objective, the optimal $\ c\ $ must be in the opposite direction to its gradient, so \begin{align}
\lambda&=-\sqrt{{\Large\sum_{i=1}^n}{\Large\sum_{j=1}^n}\frac{m_im_j\arccos\big(\langle c,p_i\rangle\big)\arccos\big(\langle c,p_j\rangle\big)\langle p_i,p_j\rangle}{\sqrt{1-\langle c,p_i\rangle^2}\sqrt{1-\langle c,p_j\rangle^2}}}\ .
\end{align}
If we take $\ w_i=\langle c,p_i\rangle\ $ as a set of $\ n\ $ unknowns in the above equations, they must satisfy the following $\ n\ $ simultaneous non-linear equations
$$
w_j=\lambda(w)^{-1}{\Large\sum_{i=1}^n}\frac{m_i\arccos\big(w_i\big) \langle p_i,p_j\rangle}{\sqrt{1-w_i^2}}\ .
$$
I doubt if there's any simple expression for the  solution.  I expect the best you'd be able to do is solve them numerically for any given values of the $\ m_i\ $ and $\ p_i\ $.  Alternatively, it's probably going to be simpler to solve the optimisation problem directly with a gradient projection method.